# scanning a webpage for urls with ruby and regex

Tags: ruby, uri, net-http

I'm trying to create an array of all links found at the below url. Using `page.scan(URI.regexp)` or `URI.extract(page)` returns more than just urls.

How do I get just the urls?

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI("https://gist.github.com/JsWatt/59f4b8ce6bbf0c7e4dc7")
page = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
p page.scan(URI.regexp)
p URI.extract(page)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to extract links (`<a href="...">` elements) from the text file then it seems better to parse it as real HTML with Nokogiri, and then extract the links this way:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# Parse the raw HTML text
doc = Nokogiri.parse(open('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JsWatt/59f4b8ce6bbf0c7e4dc7/raw/c340b3fbcab7923e52e5b50165432b6e5f2e3cf4/for_scraper.txt'))

# Extract all a-elements (HTML links)
all_links = doc.css('a')

# Sort + weed out duplicates and empty links
links = all_links.map { |link| link.attribute('href').to_s }.uniq.
        sort.delete_if { |h| h.empty? }

# Print out some of them
puts links.grep(/store/)

http://store.steampowered.com/app/214590/
http://store.steampowered.com/app/218090/
http://store.steampowered.com/app/220780/
http://store.steampowered.com/app/226720/
...
```